# can i change routing onmouseenter event in react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

when i click the Link router Link works perfectly but how can i access router link onmouseenter event please suggest me.its kind of a hover effect.when i hovered the router link menu its active and go to the link destination.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Example from './Example.js';
import About from "./About.js"; 
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/about">About</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>

            <hr />

            <Route exact path="/" component={Example} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          </div>
        </Router>
        <Example />
      </div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: have you tried `history.push`?

Comment: no i did not can you explain or show me a idea

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt seem like a good idea changing history state onmouseover.

Anyways for your scenario call below within onmouseeenter:

```
this.props.history.push(newUrl);
```

Components added to route will have history as props. For eg: Below **Example** component will have history as props

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Example} />
```

Other components not added to route mostly child components won't have history as prop. To get access to react-router history we use **@withRouter** decorator in our project. There is an option available if decorators are not used. To use decorators add "stage-3" of babel in your project.

> Update:

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

@withRouter
class App extends Component {
...
}
```

Add `history` to props. Now within component use: `this.props.history.push(newUrl);`

Comment: Adding stage-3 is a configuration you should add in *.babelrc* presets. Google it if you need some clarifications around it